# Incrementing class with add row/clone in JQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use jQuery to add a new row to a table, and assgin an incrementing id to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307129/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-a-new-row-to-a-table-and-assgin-an-incrementing-id-to)

I've got some table rows as per below:

```
<td><input id="RS_Staff_Title1" name="RS_Staff_Title1" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input id="RS_No_WD_Staff1" name="RS_No_WD_Staff1" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input id="RS_No_Weekdays1" name="RS_No_Weekdays1" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input id="RS_No_WE_Staff1" name="RS_No_WE_Staff1" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input id="RS_No_WE_Days1" name="RS_No_WE_Days1" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><img class="remove_row" src="assets/images/delete-icon.png"></td>
```

I've then got a button which takes the last table row and clones it to the one below, therefore adding a new line using this Jquery"

```
$("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#staff tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#staff tbody>tr:last');
        return false;
    });
```

What I need to happen is for the RS_Staff_Title1 to become RS_Staff_Title2, RS_Staff_Title3 and so on - the same would happen for the other columns as well.

How can I go about acheiving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$("#add_row").click(function() {
    var row = $("#staff tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);

    newRow.find("input").each(function() {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
    });

    newRow.insertAfter(row);
    return false;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GHTN7/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$("#add_row").click(function() {
    $('#staff tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#staff tbody>tr:last')
    .find('input').attr({'name':'RS_Staff_Title'+$('#staff tbody>tr').length, 'id':'RS_Staff_Title'+$('#staff tbody>tr').length
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ahagut/5/edit).

Comment: You need to update the inputs' ids as well as the id of the row.

Comment: @StefanNeubert, thanks, I missed it but updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the inputs' ids, you can use arrays and HTML will assign the incrementing number:

```
<td><input name="RS_Staff_Title[]" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input name="RS_No_WD_Staff[]" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input name="RS_No_Weekdays[]" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input name="RS_No_WE_Staff[]" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><input name="RS_No_WE_Days[]" style="width:100%;"></td>

<td><img class="remove_row" src="assets/images/delete-icon.png"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#staff tbody>tr:last').clone(true).appendTo('#staff tbody>tr:last');
```

Comment: I believe appendTo would actually insert the new row inside the old one - insertAfter should be allright.
Besides: Where is the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var j = 1;
var arr = ["RS_Staff_Title", "RS_No_WD_Staff", "RS_No_Weekdays", "RS_No_WE_Staff", "RS_No_WE_Days"]
$("#add_row").click(function() {
    j++;
    var $last = $('#staff tbody>tr:last');
    $last.clone(true).insertAfter('#staff tbody>tr:last');
    // Chaching it again to conter for the newly added Row...
    $last = $('#staff tbody>tr:last');
    // Selecting all the td's in the newly added row..
    var $td = $('#staff tbody>tr:last td');
    $.each(arr, function(i) {
        if(i > 4)
        return false;

       $($td[i]).find('input').attr('id' , (arr[i] + j ));
        $($td[i]).find('input').attr('name' , (arr[i] + j ));
        // Not considering the Images
    });
    return false;
});​
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/e6DWQ/1/)